# Using a System.Type as a Generic Parameter for a Method

Tags: c#, .net

how to create a generic method for something like this

```
Type myType = Type.GetType(classNameType.AssemblyQualifiedName);  --gets the required type

CustomerWrapper.DeserializeJsonFromStream<myType>(stream); -- failing here
```

I would like to pass diiferent types at the above line but getting error saying "myType is variable but used as type".  How can I resolve this.?

Comment: I don't know what `DeserializeJsonFromStream` method looks like, but sometimes they have a overloaded version of the same method that should look like `DeserializeJsonFromStream(Stream stream, Type ofType)`. Do you see anything like that?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this *out-of-the-box*. *Generics* needs to be known at *compile time* so the *compiler* can generate the appropriate *IL* and *generated classes*.

However you can use *reflection* with a bit of *tomfoolery* (given the usual reflection performance hit). Here is an overly contrived example

**Given**

```
public class CustomerWrapper
{
   public void DeserializeJsonFromStream<T>(Stream stream)
     => Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name);
}
```

**Usage**

```
var wrapper = new CustomerWrapper();
var stream = new MemoryStream();

var myType = typeof(string);

var method = typeof(CustomerWrapper).GetMethod(nameof(CustomerWrapper.DeserializeJsonFromStream));

if (method == null) 
   throw new MissingMethodException(nameof(CustomerWrapper),nameof(CustomerWrapper.DeserializeJsonFromStream));

var genericType = method.MakeGenericMethod(myType);
genericType.Invoke(wrapper, new object[]{stream});
```

**Output**

```
String
```

Or if you feel lucky and like everything on the one line

```
var method = typeof(CustomerWrapper)
    .GetMethod(nameof(CustomerWrapper.DeserializeJsonFromStream))
    .MakeGenericMethod(myType)
    .Invoke(wrapper, new object[] {stream});
```

<sub>***Note** : it's worth pointing out there is usually a type parameter in most deserialization methods [`Deserialize(String, Type, JsonSerializerOptions)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserialize?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializer_Deserialize_System_String_System_Type_System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_) as such you are likely better to use them*.</sub>

---

**Additional Resources**

[Type.GetMethod Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethod?view=netcore-3.1)

> Gets a specific method of the current Type.

[MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(Type[]) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod?view=netcore-3.1)

> Substitutes the elements of an array of types for the type parameters
> of the current generic method definition, and returns a MethodInfo
> object representing the resulting constructed method.

[MethodBase.Invoke Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke?view=netcore-3.1)

> Invokes the method or constructor reflected by this MethodInfo
> instance.